# Что добавить чтобы python рекурсивно записывал файлы из папки в архив а не только саму папку?

Tags: python

```
import os  
import time  
import zipfile


source = 'C:\\Users\\PCuser\\Documents\\folder'  
target_dir = 'C:\\Users\\PCuser\\Downloads'

now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')  
target = now + '.zip'

newzip = zipfile.ZipFile(target_dir + os.sep + target, "w")

newzip.write(source)  
newzip.close()
```

Comment: У меня при выполнении программы python копирует ПАПКУ в архив, но не копирует ФАЙЛЫ из этой папки, что добавить что бы он как бы рекурсивно копировал все файлы из указанной папки в архив, пока копированных файлов в папке не останется

Comment: запускал несколько раз, но вопрос не в этом, код работает, он копирует папку из указанного места и вставляет в указанный архив, но дела в том что он копирует только папку, а файлы в ней копировать не хочет, файлы не удалены

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855095/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-directory-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так.

```
import os  
import time  
import zipfile

source = 'C:\\Users\\PCuser\\Documents\\folder\'  
target_dir = 'C:\\Users\\PCuser\\Downloads'

now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')  
target = now + '.zip'

newzip = zipfile.ZipFile(target_dir + target, 'w')   # Создание нового архива
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):            # Список всех файлов и папок в директории folder
    for file in files:
       newzip.write(os.path.join(root,file))         # Создание относительных путей и запись файлов в архив

newzip.close()
```

Comment: У меня к вам есть несколько вопросов, как с вами связаться?

Comment: live:54339f0f6c571e05 skype или почта Mihail.Nuk2002.ru@yandex.ru